# Захват методов и свойств регулярным выражением

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Есть некоторая строка вида

```
obj.X.Str().Bool().Y
```

Нужно разложить ее на составляющие - объект (obj) и используемые методы\свойства (все остальное, что начинается с точки). Мое выражение

```
(\w+)(\.([^. ]+))+
```

почему-то не работает. Флаги - gm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это вся задача, то регулярки тут не особо нужны.

```
var tokens = "obj.X.Str().Bool().Y"
            .Split('.')
            .Select((x, i) =>
                new
                {
                    Therm = x,
                    Type = i == 0 ? "Object" : (x.Contains('(') ? "Method" : "Property")
                });
foreach (var t in tokens) Console.WriteLine($"{t.Type} - {t.Therm}");
```

Вывод

```
Object - obj
Property - X
Method - Str()
Method - Bool()
Property - Y
```